# Does ubuntu one synchronize extended file attributes?

Tags: 12.10, ubuntu-one, filesystem, ext4, ext3

Ext3 and 4 filesystems, if mounted with that option, support extended file attributes with which you can add metadata to your files: author, ACLs, and actually whatever you want. Does Ubuntu One synchronize these attribute along with the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu One does not sync these, as they are file system specific. Only data within the files themselves is synchronized.